# How to filter object date less than key search date using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently new on react js and right now I have module where I want to display all the date less than equal on my key search date. let say my key search date is '2021-02-17' so from feb 17 upto the last previous data will be the output. how can I achieve it via react js?

**Here is my response:**

```
{id: 1, receive_date: "Feb 12, 2021", remarks: "11"}
{id: 2, receive_date: "Feb 12, 2021", remarks: "14"}
{id: 3, receive_date: "Feb 14, 2021", remarks: "11"}
{id: 4, receive_date: "Feb 17, 2021", remarks: "15"}
{id: 5, receive_date: "Feb 18, 2021", remarks: "18"}
```

FilterReceiveChk function:

```
let keyStatus = this.state.dateReceive.toLowerCase();

            let filterReceiveChk = dataTable

            filterReceiveChk = filterReceiveChk.filter((item) => {
         
            let objIndex = filterReceiveChk.findIndex((obj => obj.id === item.id));

            let receive = new Date(item.receive_date);
            let year = receive.getFullYear();
            let month = receive.getMonth();
            let dt = receive.getDate();

            let deposit = new Date(item.deposit_date);
            let yearDepo = deposit.getFullYear();
            let monthDepo = deposit.getMonth();
            let dtDepo = deposit.getDate();

            let dateChck = new Date(item.checkDate);
            let yearChck = dateChck.getFullYear();
            let monthChck = dateChck.getMonth();
            let dtChck = dateChck.getDate();

            let monthsArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
            if (dt < 10) {
                dt = '0' + dt;
            }

            if (dtChck < 10) {
                dtChck = '0' + dtChck;
            }

            if (dtDepo < 10) {
                dtDepo = '0' + dt;
            }


            let receiveDate = monthsArr[month] + ' ' + dt + ', ' + year;
            

            filterReceiveChk[objIndex].receive_date = receiveDate


            let receive_date = [item.receive_date]

            return Object.keys(receive_date).some(
                (key) =>
                    typeof receive_date[key] === "string"  &&
                    receive_date[key].toLowerCase().includes(keyStatus)
            );
        });
```

Here is my map function:

```
filterReceiveChk.map((check, index) => {
     console.log(check)          
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a React question since it is simply straight up JavaScript that is needed.

Using Date TimeStamps it is a simple matter of math.

So, using `.filter()` we simply choose the `receive_date`s timestamps that are <= the input date's timestamp

```js
const data = [{id: 1, receive_date: "Feb 12, 2021", remarks: "11"},
{id: 2, receive_date: "Feb 12, 2021", remarks: "14"},
{id: 3, receive_date: "Feb 14, 2021", remarks: "11"},
{id: 4, receive_date: "Feb 17, 2021", remarks: "15"},
{id: 5, receive_date: "Feb 18, 2021", remarks: "18"}];

const input = 'Feb 17, 2021';
const inputTS = new Date(input).getTime();
const result = data.filter(d=>Date.parse(d.receive_date) <= inputTS);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: where i should i put the filter method? inside the map method?